# java bad operand and identifier usage

Tags: java, syntax, identifier

practicing programming with MyProgrammingLab and getting following compile error: ApartmentBuilding.java:4: error:  expected

its also giving me the following hints:
• You should be using: isLuxuryBuilding
• Are you sure you want to use: "
• Are you sure you want to use: >=

this is the requirement:
Assume the existence of a Building class. Define a subclass, ApartmentBuilding that contains the following instance variables: an integer, numFloors, an integer, unitsPerFloor, a boolean, hasElevator, a boolean, hasCentralAir, and a string, managingCompany containing the name of the real estate company managing the building. There is a constructor containing parameters for the initialization of the above variables (in the same order as they appear above). There are also two methods: the first, getTotalUnits, accepts no parameters and returns the total number of units in the building; the second, isLuxuryBuilding accepts no parameters and returns true if the building has central air, an elevator and 2 or less units per floor.

my SC:

```
public class ApartmentBuilding extends Building {
private int numFloors, unitsPerFloor;
private boolean hasElevator, hasCentralAir;
private String "managingCompany";

public ApartmentBuilding(int numFloors, int unitsPerFloor, boolean hasElevator, boolean hasCentralAir, String "managingCompany") {
this.numFloors       = numFloors;
this.unitsPerFloor   = unitsPerFloor;
this.hasElevator     = hasElevator;
this.hasCentralAir   = hasCentralAir;
this.managingCompany = managingCompany;
}

public int getTotalUnits() {return unitsPerFloor * numFloors;}
public boolean isLuxuyBuilding() {if(unitsPerFloor <= 2 && hasElevator >= 2 && hasCentralAir >= 2) {return true;}
else {System.err.println(managingCompany + " is not luxury");}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use quotes in variable names

Change

```
private String "managingCompany";
```

to

```
private String managingCompany;
```

Also `hasElevator` is a `boolean` can't be compared to a number integer in this statement:

```
if (unitsPerFloor <= 2 && hasElevator >= 2 && hasCentralAir >= 2) {
```

The method `isLuxuyBuilding` must return a `boolean`. The `else` statement doesnt have any return value.

You can do:

```
public boolean isLuxuyBuilding() {
   if (unitsPerFloor <= 2 && hasElevator && hasCentralAir) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

See: [Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: good point but doesn't answer the problem i still get identifier error

Comment: Or just simplify and do `return unitsPerFloor <= 2 && hasElevator && hasCentralAir;`